# C++ vararg function pointer

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Does the following result in well-defined behavior? That is, if you cast a non-vararg function f as a vararg function g and call g with the arguments that f expects, does the behavior match that of calling f with those arguments?

```
class Base {};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    int getInt1() {return 1;}
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    int getInt2() {return 2;}
};

typedef int (*vfunc)(...);

int foo (vfunc f) {
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    return f(&d1, &d2);
}

int bar (Derived1 * p1, Derived2 * p2) {
    return p1->getInt1() + p2->getInt2();
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
    return foo((vfunc)bar); // Is this program guaranteed to return 3?
}
```

**UPDATE**

Is there some way I can get the program to be well-defined, even if using proprietary keywords? Such as doing some stuff like `__cdecl` mentioned here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

My end goal is to have a `matcher` function that tries matching on a list of X pointers. The matcher function takes in a predicate (not necessarily a function... might be a list) and takes in a function that it will pass the matched results to. The callback function passed to it takes the same argument types and arity as the predicate matched.

Comment: I would believe and expect the answer to be that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: When you say "proprietary keywords," what do you mean?  What compiler (and version, and settings) are you targeting?  Are you open to other, better solutions (like `std::function`)?

Comment: Stuff like `__cdecl` in Visual Studio. I'm open for other solutions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the behavior is undefined, per C++11 5.2.11/6 (`reinterpret_cast`):

> The effect of calling a function through a pointer to a function type that is not the same as the type used in the definition of the function is undefined.

The type of `bar` is `int(Derived1*, Derived2*)`.  The type of the function pointed to by `f` (the expression through which the call is made) is `int(...)`.  The two are not the same and therefore the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Would you explain which is the language linkage of the functions used in the example?

Comment: @K-ballo:  Apologies; copying and pasting are skills with which I have some trouble.  I have corrected the citation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answer is "No."

For instance, in Visual C++, a variadic function will have a different calling convention than a normal function (when using `/Gz`).

The calling convention determines what pre-call and post-call assembly code is generated, and you cannot safely mix the two.

Comment: What if one specified the calling convention to be `cdecl` for both?

Comment: @K-ballo: You might get lucky, but it is implementation dependent. I don't believe there is any rule in C++ that says the compiler has to provide you a way to specify the calling conventions yourself. In fact, the C++ standard says very little about calling conventions. (and that means *assume the worst* :)